# How to add Interface config in Ubuntu18.04 to make it static?

Tags: networking, 18.04, interface

In ubuntu 16.04, we are crafting the interface config and were adding to the file (/etc/network/interfaces.d/$INTERFACE_NAME.cfg) to make it static.

Snippet :

```
INTFCFG='auto '$INTERFACE_NAME'
iface '$INTERFACE_NAME' inet dhcp
    up ip route add default via '$DEFAULT_GW' dev '$INTERFACE_NAME' table '$INTERFACE_NAME'_rt
    up ip route add 132.10.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 132.10.0.1 table '$INTERFACE_NAME'_rt
    up ip rule add from '$SERVER_SUBNET' lookup '$INTERFACE_NAME'_rt prio 1000
    up ip route flush cache
'
```

However in ubuntu 18.04, it seems that "/etc/network/interfaces.d/$INTERFACE_NAME.cfg" does not exist. So, have tried following approach : With ansible, have tried to install ipupdown and removed netplan, as its mentioned the same config can be used if we uninstall netplan and install ifupdown. Above snippet is provided as it is in bootstrap script. However, with this change, i'm not able to login with dynamic IP also. Please suggest what I'm missing and how to achieve the requirement to add the interface config to file to make it static?

```
 - name: Install ifupdown
      apt: 
          name: ifupdown
      become: yes

    - name: UnInstall netplan
      apt: 
          pkg: netplan.io
          state: absent
      become: yes

    - name: Remove directory
      file:
        path: /usr/share/netplan
        state: absent

    - name: Remove directory
      file:
        path: /etc/netplan
        state: absent
```

Comment: I don't understand why you insist on using 16.04 type of configuration in 18.04 where it was changed. There may be other tools and utilities in 18.04 that assume netplan is used and with this you can break a lot of things. You can find plenty of examples here 
https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-basics-set-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu

Comment: Have tried adding network interface in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml ` ens4:                               
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [1.1.8.0/25, ]
            gateway4:  1.1.8.1 ` but not able to see the required ip in netstat -rn and not able to ssh with the new interface added. Please clarify what will be the right interface configuration which needs to be added ?